# How do I add a classpath to a my Android Ant build system?

Tags: android, ant, configuration

I have an Android project that holds a copy of a `.jar` file (library). I would like to include this JAR file in my Ant classpath so that Ant can link against it when I build.

I have added the path to my `.classpath` file as follows:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="mylibfolder/mylib.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

However, Ant fails to link references against the library when I run `ant debug` from the command line.

My question is, how do I configure Ant so that it includes this classpath? Note: I am building on a headless server so I cannot use Eclipse.

Comment: @Perception - yes the jar is nested in the project I am attempting to build.

Comment: @Perception - I'm not sure if you're familiar with the Android build environment, but `ant debug` performs all of the steps necessary to generate a debug build. The build.xml file used by the Android tools is quite large so I won't post it here.

Answer (score 0):

`ant debug` should automatically link it if you put the `.jar` files into the `libs` folder.